# When freezing prepared meats, is it better to freeze the meat separate from the sauce/gravy?

Tags: meat, freezing, gravy

I am making a corned beef with a glaze to be eaten next week. Is it better for me to freeze the meat + gravy together, or to freeze the meat in one container and the gravy in another?

Answer (score 4):

I use two containers when possible. The meat and the sauce usually thaw at different rates, so you end up w chunks of frozen meat embedded in thawed sauce. This can be *messy* to work with.
Once frozen, it's OK to combine meat and sauce in a single container. Just separate when thawing.

Comment: Separate containers also preserve the "option" to use the meat without the sauce/gravy/glaze for an alternate dish.

Answer (score 1):

I find that when cooked meat is frozen separately it dries out quite a lot; it will still be moist after defrosting if it's submerged in its gravy as you freeze it.